# How to do Vectors with triangles?

Tags: vectors, triangles

[image]

This is my homework and I have just started learning it and I don't really quite understand it.

Comment: What specific question do you have about this diagram?

Comment: I think that the questions they asked involves common height.

Comment: Maybe you should start to naively see p and q as arrows that start somewhere and end somewhere. Now try to create connections between points by stringing them together. For example $BC = BD + DC$. Now your homework tells you some things about these distances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
\begin{align*}
\vec{BC} = \vec{BD} + \vec{DC} = \vec{BD} + \frac{1}{3}\vec{BD} = \cdots \\
\vec{BA} + \vec{AD} = \vec{BD} \iff \textbf{p} + \vec{AD} = \textbf q \iff \cdots \\
\vec{BC} + \vec{CA} = \vec{BA} \iff \cdots
\end{align*}